# What fish have deliciously edible skins?

Tags: fish, salmon, skin

I *love* salmon skins, especially when fried or oven roasted. I also always eat the skin when I have a filet.

- What other fish have deliciously yummy skins that can stand on their own like a salmon skin can?
- Are there fish whose skins are generally avoided? Examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trout - fried in butter with almond chips. Simple, quick, utterly sublime...

Answer (score 5):

The skin of all the small fish I have tried is delicious. I have never tried, e.g. tuna skin, and I imagine that it is too tough and I also wouldn't eat shark skin.  Back when I used to eat fish, I always ate the skin, and found it to be the best part. Beware, though, as while the skin concentrates the deliciousness, it also concentrates the mercury and other contaminants, so you may consider limiting your intake.

Answer (score 3):

Salmon skin is also really delicious crisped up and mixed into sushi rolls, if you're into making that kind of stuff at home. I usually just put in the salmon skin, rice, and a little bit of avocado.

Answer (score 2):

Striped Bass and Red Snapper have great skin which you can leave on when preparing fish, and then let crisp up and eat with the fillet.

Comment: What about eaten without the fish? Can they stand on their own?

Answer (score 0):

Halibut skin is great by itself. I had it out [here](http://www.willows-inn.com/) where my brother cooks, and it was fantastic. The skin is thick enough that, when baked for a while, it can stand on its own like a cracker. That's how they served it at The Willows: baked until crisp, then topped with dollops of a clam puree and a dusting of powdered wakame. It probably wouldn't be too difficult to make something similar in a home kitchen.